# Why was a bump plumbed into my 2" drain stack?

Tags: kitchens, drain

I'm trying to figure out what is going on with how this 2" pipe was plumbed. The 90, 90, 45, 45 makes no sense to me. It seems stuff could get stuck there.

Should I pull this and let it drain through the vertical stack or is there some reason I'm missing?

[image: Kitchen sink drain]

Comment: Easy to fix, though if you haven’t had issues in the past, I wouldn’t make it the highest priority.

Comment: The white paint on the studs in that area and below suggests that there was something there in the past, or at least some reason for the drywall to have been missing in those places (and for the pipe to have to side-step).  Might help to know what the use was for the space the camera is in.

Comment: Chris, I think the room was originally used as a laundry room. There's a gas line coming out of the wall which I assume was for a dryer. It's hard to see in that photo but the point where the 2-in drain comes down and turns to the right if you continue along for the next three two by fours they have been drilled out to accommodate a 2-in pipe and I'm assuming what originally happened was the 2-in line turned there ran across those three studs and then dropped down to the 2-in cast iron floor drain with the washer tied in somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

Having remodeled hundreds of houses, I have seen many situations where something was in the way at the time of original installation, or perhaps the plumber just messed up for some reason.

At any rate, when the wall is wide open like that is a great opportunity to fix things that aren't as they should be. It's not worth the effort if the wall is already closed up, which I'm assuming yours is by now. When open, it is a simple matter of cutting out the section and using 2 slip couplers to re-install a new piece. If necessary, you could use a flex coupler with stainless steel clamps.

Hope this helps someone in the future.